# How to update screen when some item in list change flutter using StreamBuilder

Tags: android, flutter, stream-builder

I am try to update an count value that is present inside every item present in the listview. I m using Streambuilder to fetch the list up data.

While increasing the count value  of every time Streambuilder build method called again and my count data for every item got reset to the initial value.

Comment: Add some code so that we can review and help

Comment: Post your code so i can help you

Comment: Have you found the solution?